# Mac OS installer package with Readme file containing images

Tags: macos, productbuild

I'm trying to set `<readme>` tag in Distribution.xml part of the package to contain something which may contain images. For now I've tried **rtfd** and **pdf**; for **rtfd** it compains that it can't open the file because of permissions lack and **pdf** is displayed as plain text. 
So the question is: how to use something that may contain images with Distribution.xml

Comment: why not set your rtfd file/folder permissions correctly when the app is first launched?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann, because there is not problem with permissions as far as I can tell(dr-xr-xr-x), I believe the problem is that productbuild tries to use `rtfd`as file and as folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I didn't find solution I used some workaround:

1. Convert RTF to HTML
2. Use [this](http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter/Create) site to convert image to embeded html image and replace all linked images in the original html
3. Use html instead of rtfd in the Distribution.xml

Drawback is that it require more work to be done and html is displayed differently in the package than I saw in browsers.

Answer (score 7):

`productbuild` doesn't handle .rtfd files correctly but I have found that OS X 10.9 Mavericks doesn't handle HTML base 64  encoded images either.

My workaround is to use `productbuild` with dummmy .rtf files and then use `pkgutil` to repackage the installer.

Your `distribution.xml` file contains:

```
<welcome file='Welcome-ReplaceMe.rtf' />
```

and Welcome-ReplaceMe.rtf exists in a .lproj folder inside Resources. Once the installer is built, but before you sign it with `productsign` expand the package:

```
pkgutil --expand Installer.mpkg Installer.expanded
```

change the `Distribution` file inside Installer.expanded to use:

```
<welcome file='Welcome.rtfd' />
```

and delete the dummy Welcome-ReplaceMe.rtf and add Welcome.rftd. Finally repackage the installer:

```
pkgutil --flatten Installer.expanded Installer.mpkg
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no solution, just a creative workaround :)

I tried to apply the existing answers.

An HTML file with embedded images (base64 encoded) didn't work in my case

So I tried to get the image file inside the package, right next to the HTML file and something like `<img src="./success.png" alt="success">`, which didn't work either :/

My out-of-the-box solution was to just use an emoji instead of the image. In my case all I wanted was this green checkmark you'd see on the conlusion screen anyways. There's an emoji (✅) that looks quite similar.